# array empty after subscribe angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular, asynchronous

i want to push the data i get from an api call in an array but this won't work:

```
export class DisplayProductComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() CheckBox: string;

  constructor(private serverService: ServerService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  products: any = [];
  id: any;
  test: any =[];
  private sub: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params['slug'];
    });
    this.getCategoryByID(this.id);
    const productsToDisplay = this.products.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element)
    })
  }
  getCategoryByID(slug) {
    this.serverService.getProductByCategory(slug)
      .subscribe(
        (response) => response.map(product => {this.products.push(product)}),
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );  
  }
};
```

I have problem with the forEach because that say me this.products is empty

Comment: can you please check the array content in this part of code : 
`subscribe(
        (response) => { console.log(response);
response.map(product => {this.products.push(product)}) }`

Comment: where did you want i check?

Comment: i want you to log the content of the response coming from the service

Comment: here is the console.log:
https://www.noelshack.com/2018-10-4-1520503127-2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you log the products before service work finish ( asynchrounous)

You can try this as solution :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.id = params['slug'];
    });
    this.getCategoryByID(this.id);
  }
  getCategoryByID(slug) {
    this.serverService.getProductByCategory(slug)
      .subscribe(
        (response) => { fillProducts(response); },
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );  
  }
  fillProducts(response : any){
     response.map(product => {this.products.push(product)});
     const productsToDisplay = this.products.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element)
    });
  }
```

regards,

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the forEach before the result of

```
this.serverService.getProductByCategory(slug)
        .subscribe(
            (response) => response.map(product => {this.products.push(product)}),
            (error) => console.log(error)
        );
```

So you should put the foreach inside the result of the subscribe:

```
     this.serverService.getProductByCategory(slug)
        .subscribe(
            (response) => {response.map(product => {this.products.push(product)})
  const productsToDisplay = this.products.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element)
    })},
            (error) => console.log(error)
        );
```

Keep in mind that the .subscribe() is asynchronous, so the result of it may be executed later even if it is called before another instruction

Comment: Thank for the help. I already try this but i need a global array of this.products to use it in other function. the forEach is just here for test that this.products is not empty.

Comment: Where do you want to use products[] ? maybe update your question with the code where we can see where it is used

Comment: i didn't write the code yet. My page look like https://www.noelshack.com/2018-10-4-1520502524-1.png
this is 2 different component: left filtrer right displayproduct. Displayproduct receive an array with true or false for each filter.          So i need an array of all display product to apply filter on it.